# Why is $\mathbb{F}_2^n/C\cong \mathbb{F}_2^{n-k}$?

Tags: coding-theory

> Why is $\mathbb{F}_2^n/C\cong \mathbb{F}_2^{n-k}$?

More context: $C\subset \mathbb{F}_2^n$ is a $[n,k,d]$-Code. I want to use the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms and construct an endomorphisme $\mathbb{F}_2^n\to \mathbb{F}_2^{n-k}$ such that $\ker (\mathbb{F}_2^n\to \mathbb{F}_2^{n-k})=C$.

The mos obvious way for me would be $\mathbb{F}_2^n\to \mathbb{F}_2^{n-k}, (x_1,..,x_n)\mapsto (x_1,..,x_{n-k-1},x_{n-k})$, but how is the kernel of this homomorphism $C$?

Comment: By definition, $C$ is a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What if you use the parity check matrix as the matrix of the linear transformation?